# функция find для string и char *

Tags: c++, строки, ооп, char

пишу код который будет искать в переменной string символы из массива string с помощью функции find, но когда он компилируется выдает ошибку
Ошибка  C2676   бинарный "==": "std::string" не определяет этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному оператору. Пробовал сравнивать не через функцию, но там ошибка мол нельзя сравнить char * и string. Помогите пж

```
class Password
{
private:
    static const int Size = 10; 
    string forbiddenSymbol[Size] = { " ", "~", "?", "\"", ";", "^", ":", "+", "=", "'" };
public: 
    Password(string passwordMeaning)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < passwordMeaning.length(); i ++)
        {
            if (find(forbiddenSymbol, forbiddenSymbol + Size, passwordMeaning[i]))
            {
                cout << "";
            }
        }   
    }
};
```

Comment: Да не мучайтесь, используйте [`find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), а то смотреть больно... У вас же проблема в том, что вы вместо символов начинаете искать строки.